# Using pahole (from dwarves package) on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, elf, dwarf

Is there a way to easily configure/install the dwarves Linux package/tools on Windows systems? I need to use the pahole command in an automation script that will be run on Windows systems.

I'm not too familiar with Linux systems, but I was able to get the pahole command working on a system running Ubuntu Linux. I'm not sure how to go about porting this package from Linux to Windows.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You may have some degree of success to compile it under cygwin, however, the only platforms supported as stated in the README are Mandriva, Debian and Fedora (though they seem pretty out of sync with the product based on the version.) which may potentially indicate no one else tried.

I'm also not sure what the benefit is to do cross-platform analysis of dwarf stabs. Potentially the IDA disassembler does offer some sort of support to ELF and DWARF, so maybe that can help you?